# react-hook-form - watch not rendering updated value before form submit

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hook-form, react-query

I'm struggling with the following registration form.

Code: See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Welyweloo/560a4fb7f63851d1c7f44255d3ebd07c)

[image]

*Expectations*

- In an IONIC app, I'm using react-hook-form and yup for the fields validation
- Clicking on the submit button ("Passer à mon adhésion") should redirect me on the next page, only if there are no validation errors and no user found with such email (ie. userData is undefined) in the db
- If the email is already used (userData is not undefined anymore), display an error

*What I tried*

- Using [watch](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/watch), to get the email field value (which will allow my query to run), then adding the relevant conditions in my submit callback function to perform either the redirection either block the user at this page with the error displayed
- Using [useWatch](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usewatch), to do the same as above
- Using [getValues](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/getvalues), to do the same as above. I called getValues in the callback function right above the logic, then I use a state to store the email. This state value was used to enable the query.
- Disabling the submit button while the query is loading, so once completed I have either data or errors

*Issue*

I don't know how to reach the expected result. I believe that I'm not using watch or useWatch properly since they do not update properly.
Right now with solutions I used :

- Using getValues solution, I need to click the submit button two times to get the expected error to display
- Using watch or useWatch, the retrieved value only changes after the click on submit and I'm still redirected on my "enroll" page. Yet, if I go back to the previous page (with the registration form) and press submit again, I know see the error
- Disabling the submit button, it seems the email field is only detected as updated once I click on the submit button
  Code: See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Welyweloo/560a4fb7f63851d1c7f44255d3ebd07c)

Comment: Share some code please.

Comment: @DevonRay there's a link to a gist at the top of the message, you can see the whole code I'm referring to.